# Align span to center of div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to find a way how to understand and solve this problem with centering span in a div. My problem is that when the window is resized the table shrinks and the text in first column gets wrapped onto second line which is fine but it causes the bottom border to be out of alignment with rest of row, alternatively when I put `min-height` on the line which solves the unaligned bottom border but then the span in first column is stuck to the top. I tried to find how to align span in div but the most common practice that I found which used absolute position doesn't work really well since the content now doesn't fit well within the box.

I made an jsfiddle here which roughly shows the problem, if you add `min-height: 34px;` to `.table-cell` class it will solve the aligned line but then the spans are not centered.

https://jsfiddle.net/xonh5rq6/32/

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're not using a `<table>` for this?

Comment: @JonUleis It was done through flexbox, I just wanted to adjust it. I have probably brainfart moment now but also I have available data for column that I am iterating on, not row, so I think it wouldn't be ideal for table ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Answer for Question: "Align span to center of div"

To align the `span` tag to the center of the `div`, just use "CSS Flexible Box Layout" directly to the `span` tag.

```
.table-cell-service {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Working Solution : 1

```css
.table {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  width: 500px;
}

.table-cell {
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 13px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  min-width: 60px;
  min-height: 34px;
}

.table-cell-service {
  border-bottom: dotted #808080;
  /* This aligns the span in the center of the div */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="table-cell">
      <span class="table-cell-service">My very long Text My very long Text</span>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      <span class="table-cell-service">My Text</span>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      <span class="table-cell-service">My Text</span>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      <span class="table-cell-service">My Text</span>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      <span class="table-cell-service">My Text</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="table-cell">
      <span>My Text</span>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      <span>My Text</span>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      <span>My Text</span>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      <span>My Text</span>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      <span>My Text</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="table-cell">
      <span>My Text</span>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      <span>My Text</span>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      <span>My Text</span>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      <span>My Text</span>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      <span>My Text</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="table-cell">
      <span>My Text</span>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      <span>My Text</span>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      <span>My Text</span>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      <span>My Text</span>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      <span>My Text</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="table-cell">
      <span>My Text</span>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      <span>My Text</span>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      <span>My Text</span>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      <span>My Text</span>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      <span>My Text</span>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

This above solution solves the problem and raises another, that it makes all width of the `span` tag to the same. It makes the `border-bottom` property weird by expanding the 'dotted-line' to the full width available.

> To make the `border-bottom` to the same width of the text above in the `span`

Add the `width` and `margin` property together with the values below to fix the new problem if wanted.

```
.table-cell-service {
  width: fit-content;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Working Solution : 2

```css
.table {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  width: 500px;
}

.table-cell {
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 13px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  min-width: 60px;
  min-height: 34px;
}

.table-cell-service {
  border-bottom: dotted #808080;
  
  /* This aligns the span in the center of the div */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  
  /* These blocks are added to shrink width as well as the border-bottom */
  width: fit-content;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="table-cell">
      <span class="table-cell-service">My very long Text My very long Text</span>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      <span class="table-cell-service">My Text</span>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      <span class="table-cell-service">My Text</span>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      <span class="table-cell-service">My Text</span>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      <span class="table-cell-service">My Text</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="table-cell">
      <span>My Text</span>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      <span>My Text</span>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      <span>My Text</span>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      <span>My Text</span>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      <span>My Text</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="table-cell">
      <span>My Text</span>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      <span>My Text</span>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      <span>My Text</span>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      <span>My Text</span>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      <span>My Text</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="table-cell">
      <span>My Text</span>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      <span>My Text</span>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      <span>My Text</span>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      <span>My Text</span>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      <span>My Text</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="table-cell">
      <span>My Text</span>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      <span>My Text</span>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      <span>My Text</span>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      <span>My Text</span>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      <span>My Text</span>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

The `width: fit-content;` declaration makes the width of the `span` to the exact width of the text inside in it along with the "bottom border line". And the `margin: 0 auto;` aligns the 'span' in center by adding side margins.

I hope this may solve the problem.

> According to the comment of @user8336738

Solution for aligning the lines of cells and also align the `span` tag in both vertical and horizontal axis. Add these lines to the `div` container.

```
.table-cell {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

A little JavaScript is used to align the lines of table cells to the same.

```
<!-- Script for making the table cells to the same size -->
<script>
  // Getting all the table cells which is the 'div' around the 'span' tag
  let tableCells = document.querySelectorAll(".table-cell")

  // Looping througn each cell and getting the maximum height
  let maximumHeight = 0
  tableCells.forEach((cell) => {

    let cellHeight = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(cell).height)
    if (cellHeight > maximumHeight) {
      maximumHeight = cellHeight
    }

  })

  // Setting the maximum height as height of all the 'div' 
  tableCells.forEach((cell) => {cell.style.height = `${maximumHeight}px`})

</script>
```

Working Solution : 3

```css
.table {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  width: 500px;
}

.table-cell {
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 13px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  min-width: 60px;
  min-height: 34px;
  
  /* These lines vertically center-aligns the content inside this element*/
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.table-cell-service {
  border-bottom: dotted #808080;
  
  /* This aligns the span in the center of the div */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  
  /* These blocks are added to shrink width as well as the border-bottom */
  width: fit-content;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
<div class="column">
  <div class="table-cell">
    <span class="table-cell-service">My very long Text My very long Text</span>
  </div>
  <div class="table-cell">
    <span class="table-cell-service">My Text</span>
  </div>
  <div class="table-cell">
    <span class="table-cell-service">My Text</span>
  </div>
  <div class="table-cell">
    <span class="table-cell-service">My Text</span>
  </div>
  <div class="table-cell">
    <span class="table-cell-service">My very very very long Text which may increase the container height</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="column">
  <div class="table-cell">
    <span>My Text</span>
  </div>
  <div class="table-cell">
    <span>My Text</span>
  </div>
  <div class="table-cell">
    <span>My Text</span>
  </div>
  <div class="table-cell">
    <span>My Text</span>
  </div>
  <div class="table-cell">
    <span>My Text</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="column">
  <div class="table-cell">
    <span>My Text</span>
  </div>
  <div class="table-cell">
    <span>My Text</span>
  </div>
  <div class="table-cell">
    <span>My Text</span>
  </div>
  <div class="table-cell">
    <span>My Text</span>
  </div>
  <div class="table-cell">
    <span>My Text</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="column">
  <div class="table-cell">
    <span>My Text</span>
  </div>
  <div class="table-cell">
    <span>My Text</span>
  </div>
  <div class="table-cell">
    <span>My Text</span>
  </div>
  <div class="table-cell">
    <span>My Text</span>
  </div>
  <div class="table-cell">
    <span>My Text</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="column">
  <div class="table-cell">
    <span>My Text</span>
  </div>
  <div class="table-cell">
    <span>My Text</span>
  </div>
  <div class="table-cell">
    <span>My Text</span>
  </div>
  <div class="table-cell">
    <span>My Text</span>
  </div>
  <div class="table-cell">
    <span>My Text</span>
  </div>
</div>

</div>


<!-- Script for making the table cells to the same size -->
<script>
  // Getting all the table cells which is the 'div' around the 'span' tag
  let tableCells = document.querySelectorAll(".table-cell")

  // Looping througn each cell and getting the maximum height
  let maximumHeight = 0
  tableCells.forEach((cell) => {

      let cellHeight = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(cell).height)
      if (cellHeight > maximumHeight) {
          maximumHeight = cellHeight
      }

  })

  // Setting the maximum height as height of all the 'div' 
  tableCells.forEach((cell) => {
      cell.style.height = `${maximumHeight}px`
  })

</script>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but there is still a problem that the lines of cells are not aligned and the text in first column where it is only on one line is not vertically aligned. If I set height to the cells to align the lines then it will also separate the text and dotted line on the one line text which I don't wanna.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

if this is what you are looking for then I have added below code inside table-cell class

```
display:flex;
justify-content:center;
```

Comment: There is one more problem and that is if you wanna align the bottom borders, so you can set  `min-height:34px` on the table-cell, but then if you will set it to flex it will show the dotted border separated from text on the one line texts